# Find all words placed on a Scrabble board

Tags: python

Any idea whats a simple and fast way to get all words placed on a Scrabble board while the board is represented by 2D Array of chars?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to [Artsiom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372616/find-all-words-placed-on-a-scrabble-board/6373230#6373230), but covers for the fact that a Scrabble board will have spaces in between words.

So assuming your "2D Array of chars" looks like this:

```
board = [['s','t','a','c','k',' ',' ',' '],
         ['p',' ',' ','a',' ','c',' ',' '],
         ['o','v','e','r','f','l','o','w'],
         ['o',' ','a','t',' ','a',' ','a'],
         ['n','o','t',' ',' ','m','a','t'],
         [' ',' ','e',' ',' ',' ',' ','e'],
         [' ',' ','r',' ',' ',' ',' ','r'],
         [' ','e','y','e','s',' ',' ',' ']]
```

You can do the following:

```
import itertools
rows = (''.join(row) for row in board)
columns = (''.join(column) for column in zip(*board))
words = [word for line in itertools.chain(rows,columns) for word in line.split() if len(word) > 1]
```

Which gives:

```
['stack', 'overflow', 'at', 'not', 'mat', 'eyes', 'spoon', 'eatery', 'cart', 'clam', 'water']
```

What we're doing is converting each row and column of characters in to strings like `'not   mat'` and then using [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to throw away the spaces to give us a list of words, throwing away anything that's one letter long.

Using [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) just allows us to loop through the rows and columns in a single list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

Search top to bottom in each column for contiguous sets of characters then search left to right in each row for the same. Its going to be O(n^2) but I don't think you'll be able to get much better.

Comment: I also got a list with all positions of each letter placed on the board, couldn't this list be used somehow in conjunction with the fact that all words are connected by one letter?

Comment: Its possible but I don't think that it would improve your performance by that much. A scrabble board isn't that big and you are most likely still going to have to inspect all of the letters.

Answer (score 0):

If i am correctly understood you than you can also try to use something like this:

```
a = [['w','o','r','d'],
     ['i','p','o','d'],
     ['k','u','a','k'],
     ['i','s','d','s']]

lines = (''.join(line) for line in a)
rows = (''.join(line) for line in zip(*a))

print list(lines)
print list(rows)
```